# How to redirect to another page with jQuery Autocomplete item click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, ajax

I need to redirect to another page when I click to Autocomplate Text Box . I try to put

```
select: function(event, ui) {
                            window.location.href = 'Search.aspx?q=' + ui.item.value;;
                        },
```

but it does not work when i click? What am ı need to solve this ?

```
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText();
        });
        function SearchText() {
            $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "AutoCompleteService.asmx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                        data: "{'TurAdi':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                        idm: document.getElementById('txtSearch').value,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);
                        },
                        select: function(event, ui) {
                            window.location.href = 'Search.aspx?q=' + ui.item.value;;
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    </script>


 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="searchtxtb oval autosuggest" Width="172px"  Height="25px"  BackColor="White"  Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#666666" onfocus="if(this.value =='ARA:Tur, bölge veya belde adı' ) this.value=''"
                           onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='ARA:Tur, bölge veya belde adı'" value="ARA:Tur, bölge veya belde adı"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete Select Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240849/autocomplete-select-redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select: function (event, ui) { ... }` should be moved to be a sibling of `source`, because it is an option of `autocomplete` not of `ajax`.

Like this -

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText();
        });
        function SearchText() {
            $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
                // Put it here, as part of the autocomplete options.
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    window.location.href = 'Search.aspx?q=' + ui.item.value;;
                },
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "AutoCompleteService.asmx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                        data: "{'TurAdi':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                        idm: document.getElementById('txtSearch').value,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);
                        },

                        // Moved out of here, since it was an ajax
                        // option and it is unrelated to ajax.

                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    </script>


 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="searchtxtb oval autosuggest" Width="172px"  Height="25px"  BackColor="White"  Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#666666" onfocus="if(this.value =='ARA:Tur, bölge veya belde adı' ) this.value=''"
                           onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='ARA:Tur, bölge veya belde adı'" value="ARA:Tur, bölge veya belde adı"></asp:TextBox>
```