# How to redirect to another page with jQuery Autocomplete depending on the id of the selection

Tags: jquery, redirect, hyperlink, autocomplete

I am new to all this but im here to learn. I'm sure this is not a big problem, but i have been trying for hours and couldnt find the solution. So i hope someone here can help me out.

What im trying to do is, retrieve and show some data from my table(city names), and then when someone selects a city, it redirects him to another page which is populated with some data  depending on the cityid of the chosen city.

I tried to solve this in 2 ways. Ill post the code for both so if anyone knows the answer for either i would be gratefull and ill explain what the problem is.

1) First try:

This is my script for autocomplete :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    { label: "<?php echo $row_rsCityCountry['cityName']; ?>,
    <?php echo $row_rsCityCountry['countryName']; ?>",
    data: "questionnaire.php?cityid=<?php echo $row_rsCityCountry['cityid']; ?>" }];

    $( "#rightSearchField" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);
            response(results.slice(0, 10));
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) { 
            window.location.href = ui.item.data;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem here is, my autocomplete does retrieve city and country name from database, but it only shows 1 row(record). It is not possible for me to make it a repeat region so I'm not sure how to make it show all . Also, important thing, it does recognize the cityid and when I click on the record it does go to the questionnaire page and shows the id of the selected record. So that part is working as intended.

2)Second try:

This is my script for autocomplete :

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $("#auto").autocomplete({ 
        source: "search.php", 
    select: function( event, ui ) { 
        window.location.href = "questionnaire.php?cityid=<?php echo 
            $row_Recordset1['cityid']; ?>";
        } 
});
});
</script>
```

The problem with the second try is, it shows all the records now, but when i click on any of them it redirects me to the questionnaire page but it doesn't recognize the id of the clicked record.

I know this was long, but i hope someone can help me with my problem. If I didn't explain it well, please tell me and I'll try my best to do it again. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you please add the code where you are populating the value into the variable.. `$row_rsCityCountry`  Since it contains only the first row and you are not iterating over the whole result set that is why the autocomplete is showing a single row for the first solution.

Comment: I edite the code ahmed so u can take a look now. Hope thats what u meant. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete Select Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240849/autocomplete-select-redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, it iterates over the result set (notice the while loop).

```
mysql_select_db($database_MyWorldTaxi, $MyWorldTaxi);
$query_rsCityCountry = "SELECT cityName, countryName, cityid 
FROM city 
ORDER BY cityName";
$rsCityCountry = mysql_query($query_rsCityCountry, $MyWorldTaxi) or die(mysql_error());
// $row_rsCityCountry = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCityCountry);
$totalRows_rsCityCountry = mysql_num_rows($rsCityCountry);


<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        <?php while( $row_rsCityCountry = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCityCountry) ) : ?>
        { 
            label: "<?php echo $row_rsCityCountry['cityName']; ?>, <?php echo $row_rsCityCountry['countryName']; ?>",
            data: "questionnaire.php?cityid=<?php echo $row_rsCityCountry['cityid']; ?>" 
        },
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        ];

    $( "#rightSearchField" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);
            response(results.slice(0, 10));
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) { 
            window.location.href = ui.item.data;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```