# jQuery UI autocomplete go to url on select

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am just wondering how I would go to a url on click from the results returned. My jQuery is as follows:

```
$('#input').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'script.php',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And my script.php is returning:

```
[
    {
        "label":"Text to display",
        "url":"Url to go to"
    }
]
```

I am finding the autocomplete instructions pretty lacking, but but my understanding is I need to do something with 'select'?

Comment: Does any of the answers below solve your problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete Select Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240849/autocomplete-select-redirect)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you pass to the source an callback, it works without using:

```
$('#input').autocomplete({
  source: 'script.php',
  select: function(event, ui){
    console.log(ui.item.url)
    // redirect to url
     // window.location = ui.item.url
  }

});
```

[**Here's a plunk.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FcUxwp1fAXinR5jRq8YY?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the select event then use a simple window.location.href to direct the user to what ever link they clicked.

Something along the lines of this.

```
$( "#input" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {
    var label = ui.item.value;

    window.location.href = link;
});
```

This is just a raw untested example.